# How to apply limit and order by for update function of the adapter in magento?

Tags: mysql, model, database-update

I am trying to update a single row of my model. My requirement is I have certain conditions which will return a set of rows and I want to update only the row with the highest id (or latest). I am using the function Update defined in Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface.

Is there a way to pass the limit and order by to the update query.

So far What I have written is following -

```
$updateCond[]         = $adapter->quoteInto('id in (?)', $ids);
$updateCond[]         = $adapter->quoteInto('test_id in (?)', $test_ids);
$adapter->update($tableName, array("status" => $status), $updateCond);
```

My $updateCond will return more than one row, But I only want to update a single row. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: create update query and use $adapter->query($query)

Answer (score 1):

Is it ok to make a select on your highest id before and then to update the status for this id ?

It should look like at something like this :

```
$highest_id = $adapter->fetchCol(
    $adapter->select()
        ->from(
            $tableName,
            array('status' => '("'.$status.'")')
        )
        ->where('id in (?)', $ids)
        ->where('test_id in (?)', $test_ids )
        ->group('id')
        ->having('id = MAX(id)'),
    'id'
);

$adapter->update(
    $tableName,
    array('status' => $status),
    array('id = ?' => $highest_id)
);
```

It's also possible with a single direct sql query :

```
$updateCond[] = $adapter->quoteInto('id in (?)', $ids);
$updateCond[] = $adapter->quoteInto('test_id in (?)', $test_ids);
$update = 'UPDATE '.$tableName.' SET status="'.$status.'" WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $updateCond).' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
$adapter->query($update);
```

Comment: I think about this first but then noticed that Mysql supports limit and order by in Update query. I was curious whether its possible to do it in magento.. If there is no issues(like perfomance or bad practice ) in using this then its perfect. thanks

Comment: Just noticed its two different queries, We can give the highest_id query as a string to the update query right ? So can avoid one round trips ?

Comment: Indeed you can do it that way or with $adapter->updateFromSelect() method if you want to avoid 2 queries, I updated my answer above.

Comment: What is the meaning of the from function arguments. I am not able to get correct result from that select query inside updateFromSelect. Thanks

Comment: Actually the select query returns all the rows matching the where conditions and the row contain status value as the given status value. 
If I replace the array content with "status" and "id". It returns the rows matching the where conditions.

Comment: Arf sorry it seems that it's not possible with methods update() and updateFromSelect() of the adapter. You can do it only with direct sql (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way but i haven't tested

```
$select = $adapter->getSelect();
...
...
...
$select->order('DESC');
$select->limit(1);
```

Comment: quoteInto is not a variable I guess, tried not working

Comment: How to integrate this to Update ?

Comment: updated ans pls check

Comment: How to integrate this select to the update query ?